# what information facebook allow to access of any user login through his/her own site

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i make a simple mvc application in which user login to facebook from my own site give the permission to access his/her public information.
Proceeding to task, i get the accessToken of user.
So my question is- Howmany and what information facebook allow to access
I want to know a list of key value of information that i can access
as i get user name by sipmle code

```
        var client = new FacebookClient(accessToken);
        dynamic result = client.Get("me",new { fields ="name");
        string username = result.name;
```

So i want to know in detail about "fields" section in above code.
Please suggest and guide me.
thankyu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `/me` endpoint is described in the Graph API documentation: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

There you have a list of all possible fields. Of course you can only request those fields for which you requested in the scope when authenticated and the user explicitly granted permissions in the consent page. You can read the scopes and permissions here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/#permissions

Comment: Thanks for link.It really very helpful.But i can't able to access user's languages while i have permission for that as user_likes.Plz consider my problem.Thanks alot